# How to make the max date in a card visual unchanged so that it will not be filtered by the same date filter for other visuals?

Tags: date, powerbi, max, dax

Objective is to inform readers what is the latest available data (i.e., max date of the data set). However, I have other line chart visuals using the same date field in the x-axis. For instance, if the dataset has data up to 9th March 2023, but when the user filters date range between 1st Jan 2023 to 5th Jan 2023, the max date card visual will now show 5th Jan 2023.

I googled and tried using ALLSELECTED in DAX, but the max date is still being filtered. Below is my DAX: Latest Date = CALCULATE(format(max('dwh vw_f_attendance'[registration_date]), "dd mmmm yyyy"),ALLSELECTED('dwh vw_f_attendance'[registration_date]))

Comment: You need to use `ALL` to ignore all filters, and you need to use  `ALL` on your entire dataset not only your column. ie `ALL('dwh vw_f_attendance')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your line charts, goto the **Format** tab, **Edit interactions** and simply disable the cross-filtering of your card visual.

Comment: This works! Thanks! Not sure why the DAX method did not work :(